# org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: An exception occurred in the persistence layer. While saving a variable in DelegateExecution object

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, camunda

Facing ProcessEngineException while saving a variable in DelegateExecution in the ServiceTask execution.

I have one Camunda ServiceTask (i.e ServiceTask1) which will initiate another camunda process serviceTask (ServiceTask2) based on the fetched data from the database. During the execution of first ServiceTask, I want to save that how many processes are initiated for ServiceTask2.

Following is the log.

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: An exception occurred in the persistence layer. Please check the server logs for a detailed message and the entire exception stack trace.
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.wrapPersistenceException(ExceptionUtil.java:263) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.flushDbOperationException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:132) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperations(DbEntityManager.java:364) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperationManager(DbEntityManager.java:323) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flush(DbEntityManager.java:295) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.flushSessions(CommandContext.java:272) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.close(CommandContext.java:188) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:119) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:72) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandCounterInterceptor.execute(CommandCounterInterceptor.java:35) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobHelper.executeJob(ExecuteJobHelper.java:57) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.executeJob(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:110) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.run(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:71) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03004 Exception while executing Database Operation 'DELETE ExecutionEntity[4030c055-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]' with message '
### Error flushing statements.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.deleteExecution (batch index #6) failed. 5 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.deleteExecution (batch index #6) failed. 5 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
'. Flush summary: 
 [
  INSERT ExecutionEntity[4c54a962-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54a963-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d074-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d075-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d076-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d077-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d078-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d079-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54d07a-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f78b-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f78c-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f78d-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f78e-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f78f-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f790-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f791-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f792-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[4c54f793-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  INSERT MessageEntity[4c54f795-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE MessageEntity[4030e76d-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[4030c056-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[4030e767-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[4030e768-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[4030e769-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[4030e76a-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[4030e76b-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
  DELETE ExecutionEntity[4030c055-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8]
]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.flushDbOperationException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:131) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error flushing statements.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.deleteExecution (batch index #6) failed. 5 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.deleteExecution (batch index #6) failed. 5 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.flushStatements(DefaultSqlSession.java:254) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.flushBatchOperations(DbSqlSession.java:444) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.BatchDbSqlSession.executeDbOperations(BatchDbSqlSession.java:74) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperations(DbEntityManager.java:341) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.deleteExecution (batch index #6) failed. 5 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:149) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:129) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:122) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.flushStatements(CachingExecutor.java:114) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.flushStatements(DefaultSqlSession.java:252) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ACT_FK_VAR_EXE". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.ACT_RU_VARIABLE", column 'EXECUTION_ID_'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2101) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor229.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.64.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.executeBatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:123) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
INFO  [rahulv_workflow_dev_dt][version:current.version@][traceId:][spanId:][parentSpanId:][spanExportable:][JobExecutor[com.highq.workflow.camunda.processengine.CustomSpringJobExecutor]][2022-11-02 16:43:00,034]- com.highq.workflow.camunda.processengine.CustomJobManager.findNextJobsToExecute:Line 60 - findNextJobsToExecute :: Executed and page value is : 15
WARN  [rahulv_workflow_dev_dt][version:current.version@][traceId:][spanId:][parentSpanId:][spanExportable:][rahulv_dev_5_6.1644992100870CamundaCallServiceTask_thread4][2022-11-02 16:43:00,033]- org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logWarn:Line 146 - ENGINE-14006 Exception while executing job 4030e76d-5a9f-11ed-8b9d-00ff25863dc8: 
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: An exception occurred in the persistence layer. Please check the server logs for a detailed message and the entire exception stack trace.
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.wrapPersistenceException(ExceptionUtil.java:263) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.flushDbOperationException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:132) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperations(DbEntityManager.java:364) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperationManager(DbEntityManager.java:323) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flush(DbEntityManager.java:295) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.flushSessions(CommandContext.java:272) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.close(CommandContext.java:188) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:119) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:72) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandCounterInterceptor.execute(CommandCounterInterceptor.java:35) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobHelper.executeJob(ExecuteJobHelper.java:57) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.executeJob(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:110) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.run(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:71) ~[camunda-engine-7.15.0.jar:7.15.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

I have created one thread class which handles the saving of variable in Execution. This thread object will be executed ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) applicationContext.getBean(threadName);
SetCamundaVariableThread setCamundaVariableThread = applicationContext.getBean(SetCamundaVariableThread.class, execution.getProcessInstanceId(), variableName, variableValue);

Future<String> resultS = threadPool.submit(setCamundaVariableThread);
```